# How to delete folder after rsync --remove-source-files?

Tags: rsync, mv

I want to move a folder to an other location without using `mv`

I use

```
rsync -aAXHv --remove-source-files <source> <destination>
```

but the source folder `<source>` remains without content. Is there option that removes all empty source folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of --remove-source-files option of rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371144/usage-of-remove-source-files-option-of-rsync)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the `rsync` command with `rm`, guarded to ensure it only fires if the copy succeeds

```
rsync -aAXHv --remove-source-files {src} {dst} &&
    rm -rf {src}
```

Of course, with this combination you no longer necessarily need the `--remove-source-files`.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do my empty folder cleanup with some sanity.  I run:

```
find folder -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

repeat as many times as necessary to recursively remove empty subfolders, and ONLY EMPTY folders will be removed (because rmdir has safety built in, and it won't remove a non-empty folder) so there's no risk of my later learning that "rsync failed to move these files and my brute force rm -fr / just nuked my only copy"  ;-)

zsh protip:

```
repeat 15 find folder -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

will take care of pretty much any empty folder stack.